# csv php mysql data export - all data is being exported in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I need Name,Given phonenumber mobile notes location to all be in separate columns on my csv export using the php script below. The current code exports all of the selected data in one column for each record. Thank you!

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT who as "Name,Given" , phonenumber as "mobile", notes, location FROM `phpbb_phonelist` WHERE `activenumber` = 1'); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
   $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
if ($fp && $result) 
{     
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="phonelist.csv"');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');    
   header('Expires: 0');
   fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
   {
      fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
   }
die;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 

   fputcsv($output, $row);
```