# all csv export data is in one column

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have code of csv export,which is using by me but the problem is all data is exporting on csv in one column.but i need data must be column separated,

```html
 
 <?php
 $results= array(0=>array(name => "anil",agency=>"",phone=>"234235",cname=>"Atleta"),1=>array(name => "anil",agency=>"",phone=>"234235",cname=>"Atleta"));
 $column = array("name","cname","agency","phone");
  $writecolumn = array("Nome do Artista","Categoria","Agencia","Telefone");
  $csv_export='';
  for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
  {
      $csv_export.= $writecolumn[$i]."\t" ;
  }
  $csv_export.= "\n";
  for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
  {
      for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
      {
   $csv_export.= $results[$j][$column[$i]]."\t"; 
      } 
      $csv_export.= "\n";
  }  
   
     $categoryname=$results[0]['cname'];
     $filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.csv";
     header('Content-type: application/csv');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
     echo $csv_export;
     exit;        
    ?>
```

.

Comment: You currently use the tab character (\t) as delimiter. So your data is exported in multiple columns, but the application you use the file with probably expects another delimiter.

Comment: i am facing same problem with my code,currently i am working symphony and i am using the same code for exporting the data..but i have also faced same problem

Comment: and i am using Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019566/csv-php-mysql-data-export-all-data-is-being-exported-in-one-column/28019579#28019579

Answer (score 0):

Use array_reduce, which reduces array to a single value, by applying function to each element, with initial value passed as third parameter, something like that:

```
$result= array(0=>array(name => "anil",agency=>"",phone=>"234235",cname=>"Atleta"),1=>array(name => "name_anil",agency=>"agency2",phone=>"234235",cname=>"Atleta_2"));
$csv_export = array_reduce($result, function($acc,$row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $acc .= $value;
        $acc .= "\t";
        }
    $acc .= "\n";
    return $acc;
    },
    "Nome do Artista\tCategoria\tAgencia\tTelefone\n")
$categoryname=$results[0]['cname'];
$filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $csv_export;
exit;
```

Comment: i am confused,can you share your complete code or can you edit with my code.

Comment: working as old...but problem is not solved on my end,,, i am using ubuntu system

Comment: Actually i am using Ubuntu operating system,and there is some option like tab,comma,space check box,when unchecked all the check box,the same issues there,all data in one column.

Comment: Actually you can use different delimiter, try "," instead of "\t" in above code and see if that works, provided that you checked "comma" option while opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has delimiter (value separator) is 'tab' ('\t'). May be your CSV reading software need some configuration to start using 'tab' ('\t') as delimiter. I updated your code below and use ',' as delimiter. Microsoft Excel use ',' as default delimiter. Please try code below,

```html
 
 <?php
                $results= array(0=>array('name' => "anil",'agency'=>"",'phone' =>"234235",'cname'=>"Atleta"),1=>array('name' => "anil",'agency'=>"",'phone'=>"234235",'cname'=>"Atleta"));
                $column = array("name","cname","agency","phone");
  $writecolumn = array("Nome do Artista","Categoria","Agencia","Telefone");
  $csv_export='';
  for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
  {
      $csv_export.= $writecolumn[$i]."," ;
  }
  $csv_export.= "\r\n";
  for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
  {
      for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
      {
   $csv_export.= $results[$j][$column[$i]].","; 
      } 
      $csv_export.= "\r\n";
  }  
   
     $categoryname=$results[0]['cname'];
     $filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.csv";
     header('Content-type: application/csv');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
     echo $csv_export;
     exit;        
    ?>
```

Comment: i have tried it but did not find solution but , when i checked the tab it goes fine.

Comment: i am very frustrated,if you have any other solution please let me know

Comment: Above code should work. Is above code not working? Can you please give us details about your issue?